# Adding new properties when working with spread objects?

Tags: javascript

I have some existing code that looks like this (I can't change the function definitions of `add_from_address` or `email.send`, only what's inside the body of `add_from_address`):

```
function add_from_address(...args) {
    args.from = "foo@bar.com";
    console.log(args);
    email.send(...args).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed", error);
    });
}
```

This is the output of `console.log(args)`:

```
[ 'subscription-created',
  { subject: 'hello', user_id: user_id },
  from: "foo@bar.com" }];
```

But I was hoping to achieve this:

```
[ 'subscription-created',
  { subject: 'hello', user_id: user_id, from: "foo@bar.com" }];
```

Obviously, I could just manually add the new property to the second element of `args` as follows:

```
function add_from_address(...args) {
    args[1].from = "foo@bar.com";
    console.log(args);
    email.send(...args).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed", error);
    });
}
```

But is there a more elegant way to add properties when working with spread operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinne the object you want to add the property to is the second argument (`args[1]`), you need to add the property to that object, not the array:

```
function add_from_address(...args) {
    args[1] = {...args[1], from: "foo@bar.com"};
    email.send(...args).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed", error);
    });
}
```

That updates your array with a new object, adding (or overwriting) the `from` property.

Live Example:

```js
function add_from_address(...args) {
    args[1] = {...args[1], from: "foo@bar.com"};
    console.log(args);
}

add_from_address(
  'subscription-created',
  { subject: 'hello', user_id: 42 }
);
```

---

In a comment you've asked why not to use:

```
args[1].from = "foo@bar.com";
```

The only issue with doing that is that it modifies the object that was passed into the method. Example:

```js
function add_from_address1(...args) {
    args[1] = {...args[1], from: "foo@bar.com"};
    console.log(args);
}
function add_from_address2(...args) {
    args[1].from = "foo@bar.com";
    console.log(args);
}

const obj1 = { subject: 'hello', user_id: 42 };
add_from_address1('subscription-created', obj1);
console.log(obj1.from); // undefined, because the object doesn't have a `from` property

const obj2 = { subject: 'hello', user_id: 42 };
add_from_address2('subscription-created', obj2);
console.log(obj2.from); // "foo@bar.com", because `add_from_address2` modified it
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note how `add_from_address1` didn't modify `obj1`, but `add_from_address2` *did* modify `obj2`.

Modifying the object that was passed in may be fine in your case. In general, though, methods should leave the caller's objects alone unless the purpose of the method is to modify the object.

---

Just as a side note, if you want to you can use formal (named) parameters for the first two and rest for the...rest:

```
function add_from_address(type, msg, ...rest) {
    email.send(type, {...msg, from: "foo@bar.com"}, ...rest)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will `args[1].from = "foo@bar.com"` not do what I want, or is this simply stylistically preferable?

Comment: Sorry for basic question but finding it hard to work out how to console log  spread operators! A simple assignation does appear to do what I want, but perhaps there's a reason this spread assignation is preferred?

Comment: @Richard - No worries! I added it to the answer. :-)